# PHP: Sanitising inputs after migrating to mysqli from mysql

Tags: php, mysqli, sanitization

I've just converted my code from `mysql` to `mysqli` and I used Oracle's converter: 
https://wikis.oracle.com/display/mysql/Converting+to+MySQLi

It was my understanding from various questions/answers on Stack Overflow that inputs do not need to be sanitised if you are using `mysqli`. However it appears this isn't the case - even though I'm on `mysqli` - i can still input something with an inverted comma e.g. `what's` and it returns the error as it will try to merge anything after the `'` with the rest of my code.

Am I doing something wrong? If I still need to sanitise my input values after using `mysqli` how could I do it?

**UPDATE**

If I run a function like this on my inputs would that be enough?

```
function sanitise($str){
  $string = htmlspecialchars($str);
  $string = mysql_real_escape_string($str);
  return $str;
}
```

Comment: Where exactly did you see `inputs do not need to be sanitised if you are using mysqli`?

Comment: Input sanitization: [`mysqli::real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysqli-real-escape-string) or prepared  statements ([`mysqli_stmt`](http://php.net/mysqli_stmt)). And, yeah, do not trust code converters - if you ask me, I would never trust my code to third party tool.

Comment: @CORRUPT I've updated my question, does that look about right?